# Android Studio 2.2.3 disable auto save?

Tags: android-studio

I've just downloaded Android Studio 2.2.3 and try to build WebView app by following article from the internet.

Since I'm still a beginner in all of these (java, gradle, etc) I'm expecting that if I copy/paste some codes, Android Studio will not automatically save it in order when I made a mistake - I can just close Android Studio then open it back the project and the project will open just before I paste the new codes.

But it seems impossible to me (or I don't know how to do it) because although I never do the save (ctrl+s) after I paste a new codes, Android Studio always "remember" the codes and save it automatically to the project. This cause if I close then open back Android Studio, the codes showed by Android Studio is after I paste the new codes.

It's difficult for me to explain it in English about my problem. Anyway, for example is in Microsoft Excel. Suppose I pasted some new codes in macro (VBA), without saving it first, I run it and it turn out there is an error, besides I can just undo it - but in case I got lost (confuse because there are already too many times pasting the codes), I can just close Excel then Excel show me a warning that I haven't save it yet after I do the pasting a new codes. I can just tell Excel to close it anyway without saving then open it back the file and Excel shows the last codes before I paste the new codes. And this is not possible (or maybe I don't know on how to do it) in Android Studio as it seems it automatically save the new codes, and although I don't do ctrl+s, the next time I open this project - Android Studio show me the new pasted codes.

My question here is :

- is it possible not to let Android Studio "remember" (auto-saving) the
  new pasted codes if I don't do the ctrl+s ?
- is it possible that if after I paste a new codes I close it
  without saving, Android Studio give me a warning that I haven't saved
  the new pasted codes and give me an option to save it or to just
  close it anyway without saving ?

I'm sorry if my question is not appropriate to put here. But I don't know where the proper category here to ask. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Perhaps have a look at **Show History** on the **Toolbar** (icon is a montior with blue clock) and then local changes. This will list changed files and you can go into each and undo (CTRL Z); a green bar on the right indicates the change(s) lines. Perhaps also consider using a version control system which gives another level of historical change management.

Comment: @Mike T, thank you for your suggestion. I looked into the Show History from : VCS ---> Local History ---> Show History. But to be honest, I have my headache looking to all those lists :). Under VCS, I also found another option as you suggest : VCS ---> Enable Version Control Integration. I will start over from scratch and will try this "version control" option. Still I wonder, if Android Studio automatically saving the new pasted codes - what's the point it provides me an option to "save all" (ctrl+s) in : File---> Save All (diskette icon) ? Thanks once again, Mike.